# Replace every non letter or number character in a string with another

Tags: matlab, directory

**Context**

I am designing a code that runs a bunch of calculations, and outputs figures. At the end of the code, I want to save everything in a nice way, so my take on this is to go to a user specified Output directory, create a new folder and then run the save process.

**Question(s)**

My question is twofold:

1. I want my folder name to be unique. I was thinking about getting the current date and time and creating a unique name from this and the input filename. This works but it generates folder names that are a bit cryptic. Is there some good practice / convention I have not heard of to do that?
2. When I get the `datetime` string (`tn = datestr(now);`), it looks like that:

> tn =
>
> ```
> '07-Jul-2022 09:28:54'
> ```

To convert it to a nice filename, i replace the `'-'`,`' '` and `':'` characters by underscores and append it to a shorter version of the input filename chosen by the user. I do that using `strrep`:

```
tn = strrep(tn,'-','_');
tn = strrep(tn,' ','_');
tn = strrep(tn,':','_');
```

This is fine but it bugs me to have to use 3 lines of code to do so. Is there a nice one liner to do that? More generally, is there a way to **look for every non letter or number character in a string and replace it with a given character**? I bet that's what `regexp` is there for but frankly I can't quite get a hold on how regexps work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your point (1) is opinion based so you might get a variety of answers, but I think a common convention is to at least start the name with a reverse-order date string so that sorting alphabetically is the same as sorting chronologically (i.e. `yymmddHHMMSS`).

To answer your main question directly, you can use the built-in [`makeValidName` utility](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.lang.makevalidname.html) which is designed for making valid variable names, but works for making similarly "plain" file names.

```
str = '07-Jul-2022 09:28:54';
str = matlab.lang.makeValidName(str)
% str = 'x07_Jul_202209_28_54'
```

Because a valid variable can't start with a number, it prefixes an `x` - you could avoid this by manually prefixing something more descriptive first.

This option is a bit more simple than working out the regex, although that would be another option which isn't too nasty here using `regexprep` and replacing non-alphanumeric chars with an underscore:

```
str = regexprep( str, '\W', '_' ); % \W (capital W) matches all non-alphanumeric chars
% str = '07_Jul_2022_09_28_54'
```

To answer indirectly with a different approach, a nice trick with `datestr` which gets around this issue and addresses point (1) in one hit is to use the following syntax:

```
str = datestr( now(), 30 );
% str = '20220707T094214'
```

The `30` input (from the [docs](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datestr.html#btenptl-1-formatOut)) gives you an ISO standardised string to the nearest second in reverse-order:

> 'yyyymmddTHHMMSS' (ISO 8601)

(note the `T` in the middle isn't a placeholder for some time measurement, it remains a literal letter `T` to split the date and time parts).

Comment: Thanks! I like the sorting argument as well!

Comment: @Bill aside: there's a neighbouring utility called `matlab.lang.makeUniqueStrings` which could be helpful for making unique file names, in conjunction with `dir` to list the existing file names in a folder, it will add `_V` where `V` is a version number for duplicate names

Answer (score 1):

I normally use your folder naming approach with a meaningful prefix, replacing `':'` by something else:

```
folder_name = ['results_' strrep(datestr(now), ':', '.')];
```

As for your second question, you can use [`isstrprop`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isstrprop.html):

```
folder_name(~isstrprop(folder_name, 'alphanum')) = '_';
```

Or if you want more control on the allowed characters you can use good old [`ismember`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.ismember.html):

```
folder_name(~ismember(folder_name, ['0':'9' 'a':'z' 'A':'Z'])) = '_';
```

Comment: Sweet! Didn't even know about `isstrprop`!